# I have applied to work permit while staying as a student. What happens if my student visa is cancelled?

Tags: schengen, work, czech-republic

I came to Czech Republic to study and recently found a job. I have applied for a work permit and my application is received. Now, I am waiting for my work permit.

I have a contract signed by both parties (me, and the company) stating that I will start working as soon as I receive my work permit.
Thus, I can start at the company as an intern (without pay) immideately. This will be a great help to the process of orientation. 
However, by going to the workplace regularly means that I won't be able to attend the classes and my student visa will be cancelled.

I have declared that I will not stay in the country as a student anymore. Therefore, I would like to take this opportunity and accept to be an intern until my permit is issued.

Regardless of me working or not:
**If my student visa is cancelled when I am waiting for the work permit, does it have any effect on the process?**
Will I have to go back to my country? Or is it possible for me to wait here?

Comment: This site is for short term travel, like vacations. We have a whole other site about working and studying abroad, called [Expatriates](http://expatriates.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know about Czech law, but in many other countries:

**Just because your work is not paid doesn't mean it's not work.**

In other words you may be breaking the law by doing your unpaid internship without a work permit. I strongly recommend checking with a lawyer.

To answer your question:

**Yes, if your student visa is cancelled before your work permit is granted (and you do not have another permit that permits you to stay) then you have to leave Czech Republic.**

Also you should be aware that a sudden switch of visa may cause you problems. Depending on how long you have been studying, if you suddenly decide that you don't want to study, but instead get a job, may lead the Czech authorities to believe you didn't really mean to study at all, but instead intended to work all the time. This may lead them to reject your work permit application.

Depending on how long you have left in your course, you might want to consider finishing your studies, doing some unpaid 'training' with your company, and starting your job when your course is finished.

Comment: Just a few weeks left until this semester is finished, and I probably will not continue if my permit is granted. But thanks to your advice, I will continue attending the courses, and break off only after I have my permit.

Answer (score 1):

You are in Czech with student visa, so you must follow the rules of the visa.

If you work, the visa is cancelled, so you must return home (or in an other country where you can legitimately stay).

Probably the work permit will be cancelled and you may receive a ban on apply it for some years.

By working on student visa, you show that you do not follow the rules, so they cannot trust you for any other request (e.g. for work permit).

Comment: This does not answer my question. I have already applied for a work permit. I will not work illegaly.

Comment: Applying is not enough. You will work illegally until you get the permit. Maybe I interpret wrongly the question, but I read that you want to be an internship until you get the working permit. Maybe you should clarify the timeline (it offer both interpretations)

Comment: OK, I edit the question.